# Matplotlib fill_between(...) doens't work on PeriodIndex

Tags: matplotlib

I have being trying to make it work in many ways, but it just doesn't. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is a simple toy code

```py
index = pd.period_range('1990-1', '2000-1', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1]*len(index), 2:[10]*len(index)}, index=index)

plt.fill_between(index, x[1], x[2])
```

It won't work. It you change `index` for `index.to_timestamp()` then it works fine.

The error shown is

```py
~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   5226 
   5227         # Handle united data, such as dates
-> 5228         self._process_unit_info(xdata=x, ydata=y1, kwargs=kwargs)
   5229         self._process_unit_info(ydata=y2)
   5230 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_unit_info(self, xdata, ydata, kwargs)
   2123             return kwargs
   2124 
-> 2125         kwargs = _process_single_axis(xdata, self.xaxis, 'xunits', kwargs)
   2126         kwargs = _process_single_axis(ydata, self.yaxis, 'yunits', kwargs)
   2127         return kwargs

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_single_axis(data, axis, unit_name, kwargs)
   2106                 # We only need to update if there is nothing set yet.
   2107                 if not axis.have_units():
-> 2108                     axis.update_units(data)
   2109 
   2110             # Check for units in the kwargs, and if present update axis

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in update_units(self, data)
   1496 
   1497         if neednew:
-> 1498             self._update_axisinfo()
   1499         self.stale = True
   1500         return True

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _update_axisinfo(self)
   1532             self.isDefault_label = True
   1533 
-> 1534         self.set_default_intervals()
   1535 
   1536     def have_units(self):

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in set_default_intervals(self)
   2170                 if info.default_limits is not None:
   2171                     valmin, valmax = info.default_limits
-> 2172                     xmin = self.converter.convert(valmin, self.units, self)
   2173                     xmax = self.converter.convert(valmax, self.units, self)
   2174             if not dataMutated:

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\converter.py in convert(values, units, axis)
    207             values = [PeriodConverter._convert_1d(v, units, axis) for v in values]
    208         else:
--> 209             values = PeriodConverter._convert_1d(values, units, axis)
    210         return values
    211 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\converter.py in _convert_1d(values, units, axis)
    213     def _convert_1d(values, units, axis):
    214         if not hasattr(axis, "freq"):
--> 215             raise TypeError("Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods")
    216         valid_types = (str, datetime, Period, pydt.date, pydt.time, np.datetime64)
    217         if isinstance(values, valid_types) or is_integer(values) or is_float(values):

TypeError: Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods
```

If anyone could help me with this bug I would be really gratefull! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest matplotlib and pandas versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First correction: *index* is a name of a DataFrame attribute,
so use rather some "similar" name, e.g.:

```
idx = pd.period_range('1990-1', '2000-1', freq='M')
```

Then create your DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1]*len(idx), 2:[10]*len(idx)}, index=idx)
```

You can fill the space between both lines, but first draw the lines
themselves:

```
df.plot()
```

Then you can fill the space between them:

```
plt.fill_between(idx, df[1], df[2]);
```

(note that you wrote *x* instead of *df*).

Apparently *plt* requires either both border lines to be drawn in advance
or at least one of them. But the picture looks better when you have
both border lines drawn with another color than the space between them,
so it is more natural to draw **both** lines.